# Weird JVM verification error: Mismatched stack types

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to instrument class files using asm-framework such that based on a boolean flag at runtime, for certain set of classes, I can switch whether the base class or its sub class gets instantiated (All of this happens transparently without the user's knowledge). Here is an example quasi-asm that my program so far generates.

```
  public void createInstance();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
        aload_1 //load the string flag
        ifnull label_0
        new com.example.BaseClass
        goto label_1
       label_0:
        new com.example.SubClass
       label_1:
        dup
        ldc "a"
        aload_1   //load the string flag
        ifnull label_2:
        invokespecial com.example.BaseClass.<init>(java.lang.String)
        goto label_3
       label_2:
        invokespecial com.example.SubClass.<init>(java.lang.String)
       label_3:
        astore_1
        return
```

The problem is ASM does not complain about the generate class files. However, JVM fails when I try to run this code with the following error(partial stack trace shown here):

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError:  Mismatched stack types
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2446)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2756)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:328)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
```

Is what I am doing an impossible task with JVM ? If not, how I correct my mistake?

Similar errors I found online:

- http://objectmix.com/java/158464-strange-verifier-semantics.html
- JVM Spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#9839

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytecode verifier operates on basic blocks (the linear segments of bytecode without branch instructions or branch targets inside). So the information about the exact class at `label_1` is lost: it is either `BaseClass` or `SubClass`. That's why JVM cannot verify that you call the right constructor.

Modify the code flow so that you invoke `BaseClass.<init>` right after `new BaseClass` and `SubClass.<init>` right after `new SubClass` without jumps in between.